# This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms when building an app with visual studio

Tags: fips

I am trying to compile my program in visual studio and I am getting a FIPS Cryptographic algorithms error. I have checked the registry key and it is set to false.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had a hard time with this too. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`. Under a subkey you should see `FipsAlgorithmPolicy`. *DELETE* this registry entry and restart visual studio.

REF: https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/parser-error-message-this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms-when-net-page-has-debug-true

Comment: I didn't DELETE anything. Just navigated into the FipsAlgorithmPolicy folder and changed the "Enabled" DWORD from 1 to 0 and it worked just fine.  In the morning my computer crashed, then booted up and started installing updates, and prompted if I wanted to start windows normally.  Not sure if it was the crash or the updates that got me.  Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Delete or disable will work in your local PC, what happens when you're publishing or distributing the software? I think you should chose another cryptographic algorithm that is FIPS compliant

Comment: With deleting the key you probably won't get the error anymore. But it seems that afterwards the encrypting won't be FIPS compliant any more. May be, some other software needs this FIPS compliance.

Comment: @boboes The key that is being deleted is not the correct FIPS compliance key. There is aother key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPS. This is the key that actually deals with the FIPS compliancy.

Comment: @robert: according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811833/en-us this key is responsible for the settings: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled, at least for W2008 / W2008 R2

Comment: @boboes correct the one that I am suggesting you remove is two directories up.

Comment: I was able to set to 0 and not restart. If your company group policy refreshes upon restart the registry reverts.

Answer (score 21):

You can fix this by adding `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>` under the `runtime` section in the .config files of:

- MSBuild (example path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config`)
- Visual Studio (example path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`)

Comment: I prefer this answer since it is more generally applicable.  The FIPS policy is usually configured by your organization and propagated via Active Directory. In this case, it should not be changed globally by editing the registry.

Comment: I shut down Visual Studio 2022, then did this suggested change for both listed files, using Visual Studio 2022 (which is installed in c:\Program Files\) and restarted Visual Studio 2022, but I'm still getting this error when trying to log in to my (admittedly ancient) forms auth web app.  But I just re-read the original question, and it refers to building an app, not logging in to one... so maybe I need to do some more research here lol.  Thanks for getting me on the right track tho.  :)

Answer (score 6):

My answer was to change the registry key from 1 to 0 here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit general.  My more specific error:

> AppContainer Creation Failed with error message NONE, state This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms

Microsoft explains and lists a workaround here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/911722/you-may-receive-an-error-message-when-you-access-asp-net-web-pages-tha

Open Web.config
Locate the system.web section

Add the key:

```
*<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/>*
```

Save Web.Config, then iisreset from the command prompt.

Assumption is that company policy has set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy` with a value of `1` (and of course, that IIS is running)

Would be nice to know why this effects the installation of Python and R on Windows SQL Server 2019.

Comment: that web page linky isn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

Me helped(Windows 11):

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled set to 0
```