# Exception occurred while using ConvertFrom-SecureString with Key

Tags: powershell, encryption, securestring

Anyone please help on below.

Trying to encrypt a string using a key. While generating encrypted value, receiving below error. Where as am able to do the same on another server without any issue.

Compared on Powershell version and found both servers have identical versions. Any hints?

```
$Key = (1..16)
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypw" -AsPlainText -Force
ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $SecureString -Key $Key
```

**Receiving Below Exception:**

```
ConvertFrom-SecureString : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
At line:1 char:1
+ ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $SecureString -Key $Key
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-SecureString], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromSec
   ureStringCommand
```

**$error[0].Exception | Format-List * -force**

```
Message        : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Data           : {}
InnerException : System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS
                 validated cryptographic algorithms.
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor()
TargetSite     : System.Object InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
StackTrace     :    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig,
                 Boolean constructor)
                    at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,
                 Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
                    at System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(String algName)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.SecureStringHelper.Encrypt(SecureString input, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromSecureStringCommand.ProcessRecord()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
HelpLink       :
Source         : mscorlib
HResult        : -2146232828
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIPS cryptographic algorithms is problem here.**

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa.` and delete subkey `FipsAlgorithmPolicy` or Change DWORD from 1 to 0 for subkey `FipsAlgorithmPolicy` and restart your computer

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509354/this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptogra)