# heat.exe in WiX tooolset version 3.11.2 throws - This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms

Tags: wix, fips

When creating a web installer with WiX 3.11.2 on Visual Studio 2019, I am running into this error when I run heat.exe to gather my web sites for packaging:

> heat.exe(0,0): warning HEAT0001: This implementation is not part of
> the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
> Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException        Stack Trace:
> at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
> at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Common.GenerateIdentifier(String
> prefix, Boolean fipsCompliant, String[] args)
> at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.DirectoryHarvester.HarvestDirectory(String
> path, String relativePath, Boolean harvestChildren)
> at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.DirectoryHarvester.Harvest(String
> argument)
> at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Harvester.Harvest(String argument)
> at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Heat.Run(String[] args)

my command line is this:
$(WixToolPath)heat.exe dir $(SiteStagingFolder) -dr APPINSTALLLOCATION -cg WebSiteContent -var var.WebPackageDir -gg -FipsCompliant -sfrag -sreg -srd -out "WebSiteContent.wxs"

I understood WiX to be Fips compliant above 3.6.x.

Is there something wrong in my command parameters?

Comment: Never seen this. Maybe skim this: [1](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184698/Help-to-FIX-Error-message-This-implementation-is-n), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509354/this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptogra/45752273).

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems [to be fixed](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5672) in the upcoming WiX release [v3.14](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/milestone/16). Not sure if there is a workaround for that.